# Declaring an ArrayList that has an array for Java

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

Basically, i created a new class that contains integers and floats and made it into an array so that my array can have more than one data type:

```
public class LibRecord {
    // values for each libary user
    public int number;
    public int issued;
    public int maxLoans;
    public float fines;
    public String name;       
}

private LibRecord[] item = new LibRecord[maxUsers];
```

I need to make this into an arraylist so that i can delete,add and insert values and everytime i try to create an ArrayList with the name 'item', the compiler tells me that this name has already been used. What do i do? And how do i get this program to work so that i can call the methods in ArrayList?

Comment: I've down-voted as your question doesn't demonstrate any prior research on your part. The syntax required to create an ArrayList is referenced on many sites across the Internet. And the compiler message has specifically told you what was wrong!

Answer (score 3):

As the compiler is clearly telling you, you can't make two fields with the same name.

You need to use different names. (or get rid of the first field)

Answer (score 3):

Just replace your:

```
private LibRecord[] item = new LibRecord[maxUsers];
```

with:

```
private List<LibRecord> users = new ArrayList<LibRecord>(maxUsers);
```

Comment: Worth noting that you can also construct by calling `new ArrayList<LibRecord>()`. By supplying an integer value (`maxUsers`) you are suggesting an initial capacity for the list, but it is not required.

Comment: @DuncanJones Yes, it's not required, but if you know in advance the number of elements that you will use, it's a good practice since it will not have to reallocate its internal structure.

Comment: I completely agree! I just didn't want the OP thinking that ArrayLists *have* to be constructed that way (or get any funny ideas about them being fixed-length or similar).

Comment: Thank you, i have tried that and it works! But im trying to use the .get() method. I called the arrayList itemList and did, item = newLibRecord(); and the complier says cannot find variable .get(int). Basically, i want to be able to get a particular array from the array list by inputting the index number but im having a huge problem.

Comment: @Oyinlola In order to get an element you need to specify the list also, like: `users.get(i)` where `i` is the index.

Comment: I have done that and the program runs. I am using swing method and basically, theres a field where you input what index ypu want returned and when i press the button for java to return the particular data in that particular index, it returns the whole list. It doesnt 'get' that particular data that i am requesting for, it gives me the whole list back. what is the problem? Thank you so much for your input. I really appreciate it.

Comment: @OyinlolaOladiran You should submit another question for that, it's hard to give an answer without seeing the code.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure that you don't have two variables named `item` in the same scope.

Or else rename `item` in `private LibRecord[] item = new LibRecord[maxUsers];` to `items`